# How to install mysql 5.7.9?

Tags: mysql, installation

I'm trying to fresh install the latest version of MySQL (5.7.9) manually on Windows 7 64-bit.

When I download it from mysql.com I get the file "mysql-5.7.9-winx64.zip", but unlike previous versions it has no "data" folder and a near empty "my.ini" file.

Could someone more learned let me know what is going on with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check this link out [Windows mysql 5.7.9 MSI installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) or [Community server download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

`Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer`

`Note: MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries`.

And AFAIK, `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7` is only created with a filled out my.ini file, on a vanilla install of mysql, only after you have installed mysql server.  The zip file itself would not contain this since it is just the executables necessary to install the mysql server...

Comment: I ended up doing the following...

1) Stop MySQL Service

2) Initialize default mysql database ("data" folder) using command line
mysqld.exe --initialize --user=mysql

3) Run (start) MySQL with passwords disabled
mysqld.exe -u mysql --skip-grant-tables

4) Manually edit `mysql`.`user` table passwords